# Implementing a depth first search: incompatible objects

Tags: java, nodes, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying implement a breath-first search, for an AI program that searches through cities of romania.

however, I have had a lot of trouble with this and the latest error is

```
searches.java:153: error: incompatible types
                            current = q.poll();
                                            ^
  required: city
  found:    Object
Note: searches.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the type of your `Queue`:

```
Queue<City> q = new LinkedList<City>();
```

I have changed your `city` to `City`, since your class names should always start with an upper-case letter [as shown in this document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: A cast would also help your code compile and work nicely, but would not be an elegant solution.

Comment: Now I have the error 

'code' searches.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
                Queue<City> q = new LinkedList<City>();
                                               ^
  symbol:   class City
  location: class searches 'code'

Comment: Did you change the declaration of your `city` class to `City`?

Comment: your city class is "city" not "City" ;)